Identifying non-relativistic, scalar relativsitic and full relativistic POTCAR
How to identify if the given VASP POTCAR pseudopotential is non-relativistic, scalar relativistic or fully relativistic from the content of the file? For example, I found EATOM values in relativistic POTCAR are smaller than that in non-relativistic POTCAR.This question is peripherally related to bandstructure calculations with spin-orbit coupling (SOC). The SOC causes atom(s) to attain lower energy and thus it makes me consider EATOM. But I am not sure if this can be a correct way. Please correct if there is any conceptual flaw here; I appreciate the responses.
